# remove table row by clicking on image

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have these functions:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    if editingStyle == .delete
    {
        myItemsInCart.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

@objc func removeTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    let removeImage = tapGestureRecognizer.view as! UIImageView
    print("my taped image view tag is : \(removeImage .tag)")

}
```

I can remove rows by default, by swiping left:

[image]

but I want to remove cells by clicking the remove icon, not swiping.

Comment: Is the remove icon a `UIButton`?

Comment: no, - `UIImageView`

Comment: Try changing it to a `UIButton` and when the button is pressed you can call a delegate function to remove the `UITableViewCell`.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a protocol to accomplish this.  This is only one of multiple ways to do this.

1. Make your UITableViewController adhere to the protocol
2. Add indexPath and delegate properties to your cell
3. In your cellForIndexPath, set the cell's delegate and indexPath properties
4. In your cells subclass, add a target to your button that calls the cell's delegate's deleteCell function when pressed.

code:

```
class MyTableViewController: ItemCellDelegate {  
    func deleteCell(cell: ItemCell) {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
        myItemsInCart.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }  
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ItemCell
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
} 


protocol ItemCellDelegate {
    var delegate: UIViewController? { get set }
    func deleteCell(cell: ItemCell)
}

class ItemCell: UITableViewCell {
    var indexPath: IndexPath?
    var delegate: ItemCellDelegate?
    @objc func deleteCell(_ sender: Any?) {
        delegate?.deleteCell(cell: self)
    }
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        deleteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deleteCell), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is in the right direction but it is flawed. A cell should never be told its index path because it can change, especially when inserting, deleting, or moving rows. Change the cell's protocol so the parameter is the cell itself instead of the index path. Then `cellForRowAt` doesn't need to set anything but the delegate. Then the implementation of the delegate method will get the cell. You can query the table view for the cell's index path directly when needed.

Comment: That's a good point.  I updated to get the indexPath from the tableView by pass it the cell rather than setting as a property and passing it back.

Comment: Two more suggestions. 1) Don't call `reloadData` just to remove one row. Use `removeRowsAt`. 2) Change `deleteCell(cell: UITableViewCell)` to `deleteCell(cell: ItemCell)`. It's specific to the `ItemCell` class so no reason to keep the parameter generic.

Comment: Another good point in regard to the protocol cell type.  As far as removing a row you're definitely right, but I just left it the same as OP had it.